# Glimpse HUD not showing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, glimpse

I am trying to integrate Glimpse into my existing ASP.NET MVC 5 project. But I cannot see any HUD at bottom right corner as demonstrated in their site. I have all of the assemblies downloaded from NuGet, using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate and running in localhost.

Can anyone tell me what could be the problem? I am not finding any relevant topic online either.

Comment: Are you trying to view Glimpse on your local machine, or a remote deployment site?

Comment: @AlexDresko Local machine running the web app from Visual Studio's development server.

Comment: FTR, it is only not showing with my present application. When I created a new MVC app then it should nicely.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the browser developer tools console?

Comment: @AlexDresko Only this is printed in Chrome Dev Console `event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. Glimpse.axd?n=glimpse_client&hash=389db80a:3`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@Md.lbrahim by looking at the comment replies of you above, it seems that Glimpse is indeed active and rendering its `<script>` tags.

Can you check with the browser developer tools whether the Glimpse client is actually rendered at the bottom but maybe hidden by another element that has a higher z-index?

If you still can't get the HUD to show up, then maybe create an issue on our [issue tracker](https://github.com/glimpse/glimpse/issues) and try to provide as much details as possible (browser used, versions, other installed packages that might interfere with Glimpse rendering etc...)

Comment: Yeah, that was it. It was being pushed aside. When I made its `z-index` highest it showed. So, how can I make this change permanent?

Comment: The thing is that the Glimpse z-index is already pretty high, so the question is: can you lower the other one that is pushing Glimpse HUD aside?

Comment: Apparently, it is not `over 9000`. Cause after setting `.glimpse` to `z-index : 9999` I saw the HUD. Maybe I can use jQuery to add to the class in `document.load`.

Comment: I have had a similar problem. My site uses Bootstrap with a navbar "stuck" to the bottom of the screen. Bootstrap sets this to a z-index of 1030. I found that by adding `.glimpse-nowrap { z-index: 9999 !important; }` to my site.css, I could get the Glimpse HUD to appear

Comment: Thanks Neal, this helped me in my applications that use bootstrap.

Comment: IMHO, if a plugin isn't showing because there is page content blocking it, the answer is to update the plugin, not the page content.  I had the same issue as the OP 4 years later with Bootstrap 4 and, no, I have no intention of modifying bootstrap to make Glimpse work.  Thanks for the workaround @Neal.

Comment: Glimpse does not have a high z-index, it's z-index is 0 currently. Only setting the page footer's index to -1 allows it to render above.